# Creating time slots in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

We are trying to do an analysis of how long our staff have been working on a hourly basis for trending and forecasting purposes.

We have both the clock in (`SHIFTA_Start`) and clock out (`SHIFTA_End`) of the employees.

Then we did a datepart into 4 sections:

```
Start Time_Hour         
Start Time_min  
End Time_Hour  
End Time_min
```

[I have included the current output I have, and the desired outcome I hope to get in this image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhq0.png

Given start time and end time:

e.g.

- Start time – 940am (0940)
- End time – 615pm (1815)

It can populate very well in the respective hour slots as it is straightforward.

However if the employee work overnight, given start time and end time:

e.g.

- Start time – 930pm (2130)
- End time – 7am (0700)

The hour slots cannot be populated.

To make it short, this is part of my case statement from 0hr to 1hr

```
SELECT 

--b.*,
b.EMPLOYEENAME,
B.DEPARTMENT,

CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS SHIFTA_start,
CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.ShiftA_End,17),103) as ShiftA_End,
b.StartTime_HOUR,
b.StartTime_min,
b.EndTime_HOUR,
b.EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN b.[0H_START] < b.[0H_END] THEN  b.[0H_START] ELSE b.[0H_END] END AS [0],
CASE WHEN b.[1H_START] < b.[1H_END] THEN  b.[1H_START] ELSE b.[1H_END] END AS [1]


from
(
/*Step 2  - calculating minutes from starttime and endtime */

select a.*,

/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from start_time MIN **/
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_START],
CASE WHEN a.StartTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.StartTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((60-a.StartTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_START],


/**Calculating the number of minutes worked from END_time MIN **/
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 0 and a.[0] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[0] END AS [0H_END],
CASE WHEN a.EndTime_HOUR = 1 and a.[1] = 1  AND a.EndTime_min !=0 THEN cast(cast((a.EndTime_min) as decimal(10,2))/60 as decimal(10,2)) ELSE a.[1] END AS [1H_END]
from

(--Step 1:
/*to determine 1 or 0 using the start and end hour 
If time falls in the respective hour = 1
if time doesnt fall in the respective hours = 0*/
SELECT 

[EMPLOYEENAME], 
[DEPARTMENT],
[SHIFTA_start],
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_START_con,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN  [SHIFTA_START] !='' OR SHIFTA_START != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS StartTime_min,

[SHIFTA_end],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_END],17),103) ELSE NULL END AS SHIFTA_END_con,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_HOUR,
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_END] !='' OR SHIFTA_end != NULL THEN DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103))  ELSE NULL END AS EndTime_min,


CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 0 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [0],
CASE WHEN [SHIFTA_START] !='' AND 1 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_START],17),103)) AND DATEPART (hh,CONVERT(datetime, LEFT([SHIFTA_end],17),103)) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [1]

from [DatabaseTable].[dbo].[ATTENDANCE]

where ShiftA_Start != '' and ShiftA_End !='' and shiftA_start != shiftA_End

)a

)b
```

This is the output @Mike
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/laSKX.png

My current SQL Statement is

```
DECLARE @WORKINGHOURS TABLE (  
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    SHIFTA_START DATETIME NOT NULL,  
        SHIFTA_END DATETIME NOT NULL  
);

WITH WORKINGHOURS AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 ID,
    -- flatten the first hour to remove the minutes and get the initial current hour
  DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103)), 0) AS currentHour,
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS [SHIFTA_START],
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103) AS  [SHIFTA_END],
    DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103)) AS HourOrdinal,
    -- determine how much of the first hour is applicable. if it is minute 0 then the whole hour counts
    CAST(CASE DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103))
        WHEN 0 THEN 1.0
        ELSE (60 - DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103))) / 60.0
    END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS HourValue
FROM [TableName].[dbo].[Attendance] 


UNION ALL

SELECT ID,
    -- add an hour to the currentHour each time the recursive CTE is called
  DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) AS currentHour,
   CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS [SHIFTA_START],
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103) AS  [SHIFTA_END],
   DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour)) AS hourOrdinal,
  CAST(CASE
        -- when this is the last time period determine the amount of the hour that is applicable
        WHEN DATEADD(hour, 2, currentHour)
        > CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103) 
        THEN DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103)) / 60.0
        ELSE 1
    END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS HourValue
FROM WORKINGHOURS
-- contine recursion until the next hour is after the ShiftEnd
WHERE  DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) < CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103)
)
    SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT ID,
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_start,17),103) AS [SHIFTA_START],
  CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(SHIFTA_END,17),103) AS  [SHIFTA_END],
    HourValue,
    HourOrdinal
FROM WORKINGHOURS

) AS t
PIVOT (
    SUM(HourValue)
    FOR HourOrdinal IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
) AS pvt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Please explain why the hour slots cannot be populated? Are figures incorrect? Can you give a specific example? Is it because when you report on a given day, it incorrectly takes hours from a prior day? Perhaps give us an example of your report and why the data is incorrect.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a DATEPART. Use DATEDIFF instead. But if you really need an hour-by-hour breakdown (e.g. how many people worked how long during each hour period), you're going to need to do a DATEPART by day on top of hour/minute, then do a case statement for when the start day and end day aren't the same.

Comment: It is because those that can be populated the shiftA_start and shiftA_end fall on the same days, so they are straightforward.

whereas overnight shift requires 2 days 
eg: shiftA_start 2nd jan , shiftA_end 3rd jan

hence case statement cant be read.
my existing query already have case statements 
@Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I have already did case statement previously.

However, it doesn't populate if it is overnight due to case statement range which is 23 I suppose. 
@ZLK

Comment: @Vannessa, can you edit your question to inlcude your last comments ? it is rather hard to read a query on the comments

Comment: ok sure! thank you :-) @Squirrel

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This looks overly complex to simply group things into time segments...

Comment: for those ShiftEnd is the following day, you still want to show on the same line as the Start ?

Comment: Apply all your calculations on `DATEDIFF(SHIFTA_end,SHIFTA_start)` and don't try to subtract 45 min yesterday (or day before yesterday) from 15 min today.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send me your email addresses so I can show you the codes as the forum here restrict me from posting. Thank you and sorry for any inconvenience caused

@AlexKudryashev

Comment: You should be able to edit the question to include the codes

Comment: @Vanessa alex.kudryashev.AT.gmail.com

Comment: @Squirrel 
Hi all, I have already updated the query in the question :-)

Comment: @Alex Kudrtashev Hi all, I have already updated the query in the question :-)

Comment: @MikeD. Hi all, I have already updated the query in the question :-)

Comment: have you check out the query that i posted ? Does it suites your requirement ?

Comment: Please also post your table DML, sample data in consumable format ( insert ... values ...) and please include your expected result. Especially for cross day shfit

Comment: Hi I have added it above on the qns, pls take a look. @Squirrel

Comment: @Vannessa, seriously, have you take a look at my query, it is what you wanted, well, almost there except for the partial hour that you only added in the expected result. If it is not to your requirement, please highlight it

Comment: If your table is storing those ShiftStart and ShiftEnd times as strings instead of DATETIME values then you're in a for a heap of problems in your future. Do you have any control over the source system schema? Can you create a view to lay over this table to convert the strings automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the need to get a column for each hour this is a good candidate for using the TSQL [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) operator. Pivot takes rows of data and turns it into columns.

The first step is to create all of our rows: one for each hour and also calculate how much of that hour was applicable. I've done this by using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to generate all of the numbers from 0 to 23. A recursive CTE is a query that keeps calling itself until the anchor condition is met. The anchor condition is the `WHERE` clause of the 2nd SQL statement in the `UNION`.

Then I join on that using the `ShiftStart_Hour` and `ShiftStart_End` columns but you need to take into account when one of them is on the next day (`ShiftStart_Hour > ShiftEndHour`):

```
INNER JOIN hourOrdinals AS h ON (
        t.ShiftStart_Hour < t.ShiftEnd_Hour
        AND h.hr BETWEEN t.ShiftStart_Hour AND t.ShiftEnd_Hour
    ) OR (
        t.ShiftStart_Hour > t.ShiftEnd_Hour
        AND (
            h.hr BETWEEN 0 AND t.ShiftEnd_Hour
            OR
            h.hr BETWEEN t.ShiftStart_Hour AND 23
        )
    )
```

That join creates a row for each hour. Now we need to calculate how much of that hour was applicable using a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` clause:

```
    CAST(CASE h.hr
        WHEN ShiftStart_Hour THEN (60 - ShiftStart_Minute) / 60.0
        WHEN ShiftEnd_Hour THEN ShiftEnd_Minute / 60.0
        ELSE 1.0
    END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
```

After that we can finally use the `PIVOT` operator to get the data in the final format we're looking for. The full working example is:

```
/* CREATE TEST TABLE & DATA */
CREATE TABLE #dataTable (
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ShiftStart DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ShiftStart_Hour AS DATEPART(hour, ShiftStart),
    ShiftStart_Minute AS DATEPART(minute, ShiftStart),
    ShiftEnd DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ShiftEnd_Hour AS DATEPART(hour, ShiftEnd),
    ShiftEnd_Minute AS DATEPART(minute, ShiftEnd)
);

INSERT INTO #dataTable (
    ShiftStart,
    ShiftEnd
)
VALUES (
    '2015-08-18 07:00:00',
    '2015-08-18 21:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-20 09:40:00',
    '2015-08-20 18:15:00'
),(
    '2015-08-20 21:30:00',
    '2015-08-21 07:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-25 11:00:00',
    '2015-08-27 11:00:00'
);
/* END OF TEST DATA CREATION */

WITH hourOrdinals AS (
    SELECT 0 AS hr

    UNION ALL

    SELECT hr+1
    FROM hourOrdinals
    WHERE hr<23
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RowId,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        h.hr AS hourOrdinal,
        CAST(CASE h.hr
            WHEN ShiftStart_Hour THEN (60 - ShiftStart_Minute) / 60.0
            WHEN ShiftEnd_Hour THEN ShiftEnd_Minute / 60.0
            ELSE 1.0
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM #dataTable AS t
    INNER JOIN hourOrdinals AS h ON (
            t.ShiftStart_Hour < t.ShiftEnd_Hour
            AND h.hr BETWEEN t.ShiftStart_Hour AND t.ShiftEnd_Hour
        ) OR (
            t.ShiftStart_Hour > t.ShiftEnd_Hour
            AND (
                h.hr BETWEEN 0 AND t.ShiftEnd_Hour
                OR
                h.hr BETWEEN t.ShiftStart_Hour AND 23
            )
        )
) AS shiftHours
PIVOT (
    SUM(hourValue)
    FOR hourOrdinal IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
) AS pvt;

DROP TABLE #dataTable;
```

### But that's not good enough...

There is a problem with this method. Because we're only actually looking at the hours and not the dates it isn't going to get the right answer if some super hard worker goes on a 24+ hour shift. But there is a better way.

Instead of using the recursive CTE to generate the hours we want to match against we can use it to iterate all of the hours between the `ShiftStart` and `ShiftEnd` values. While at the same time calculating how much of each hour is applicable. In this case the anchor condition has to do with the actual data from the table instead of just simple arithmetic. Then just `PIVOT` again to get the result set in the correct format.

*Note: This query likely won't scale for more than a few thousand rows. Date range filtering and other limits on the dataset should help with that. But if you need to process more than that you will need to persist these calculations somewhere.*

This example works for shifts spanning multiple days:

```
/* CREATE TEST TABLE AND DATA */
DECLARE @dataTable TABLE (
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ShiftStart DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ShiftEnd DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @dataTable (
    ShiftStart,
    ShiftEnd
)
VALUES (
    '2015-08-18 07:00:00',
    '2015-08-18 21:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-20 09:40:00',
    '2015-08-20 18:15:00'
),(
    '2015-08-20 21:30:00',
    '2015-08-21 07:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-25 11:00:00',
    '2015-08-27 11:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-01 12:00:00',
    '2015-08-02 06:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-02 12:15:00',
    '2015-08-04 07:45:00'
),(
    '2015-08-11 12:00:00',
    '2015-08-11 12:59:00'
),(
    '1900-01-01 12:00:00',
    '1900-01-01 12:00:00'
),(
    '2015-08-11 12:00:00',
    '2015-08-11 12:15:00'
);

/* END OF TEST DATA CREATION */

WITH shiftHours AS (
    SELECT RowID,
        -- flatten the first hour to remove the minutes and get the initial current hour
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftStart), 0) AS currentHour,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        DATEPART(hour, ShiftStart) AS hourOrdinal,
        -- determine how much of the first hour is applicable. if it is minute 0 then the whole hour counts
        CAST(CASE 
            WHEN DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftStart), 0) = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftEnd), 0) THEN DATEDIFF(minute, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd) / 60.0
            WHEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftStart) = 0 THEN 1.0
            ELSE (60 - DATEPART(minute, ShiftStart)) / 60.0
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM @dataTable AS t


    UNION ALL

    SELECT RowID,
        -- add an hour to the currentHour each time the recursive CTE is called
        DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) AS currentHour,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour)) AS hourOrdinal,
        CAST(CASE
            -- when this is the last time period determine the amount of the hour that is applicable
            WHEN DATEADD(hour, 2, currentHour) > ShiftEnd THEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftEnd) / 60.0
            ELSE 1
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM shiftHours
    -- contine recursion until the next hour is after the ShiftEnd
    WHERE DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) < ShiftEnd
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RowID,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        hourValue,
        hourOrdinal
    FROM shiftHours
) AS t
PIVOT (
    SUM(hourValue)
    FOR hourOrdinal IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
) AS pvt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

### Data type conversion issues...

This answer has already gone way beyond what is a good fit for StackOverflow but let's just iron out the last detail. Your table stores dates as strings. That is a terrible design decision that will cause you lots of pain when trying to do reports from this database.

I can't see how your strings are formatted so I've just made the assumption that your conversion function is correct: `CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(b.SHIFTA_start,17),103)` If it isn't working then none of this code will work and you'll need to fix the two calls in table expression `x` below. I've also made the assumption that the table name you've given in your updated query above is correct. If not you'll need to fix that in the same table expression. It should be obvious what needs to be changed.

```
WITH shiftHours AS (
    SELECT RowID,
        -- flatten the first hour to remove the minutes and get the initial current hour
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftStart), 0) AS currentHour,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        DATEPART(hour, ShiftStart) AS hourOrdinal,
        -- determine how much of the first hour is applicable. if it is minute 0 then the whole hour counts
        CAST(CASE 
            WHEN DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftStart), 0) = DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, ShiftEnd), 0) THEN DATEDIFF(minute, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd) / 60.0
            WHEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftStart) = 0 THEN 1.0
            ELSE (60 - DATEPART(minute, ShiftStart)) / 60.0
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM (
        -- use a ROW_NUMBER() to generate row IDs for the shifts to ensure each row is unique once it gets to the pivot
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ShiftStart, ShiftEnd) AS RowID,
            ShiftStart,
            ShiftEnd
        FROM (
            -- this is where the data gets pulled from the source table and where the data types are converted from string to DATETIME
            SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_start, 17), 103) AS ShiftStart,
                CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SHIFTA_end, 17), 103) AS ShiftEnd
            FROM WORKINGHOURS
            -- this is also where you would add any filtering from the source table such as date ranges
        ) x
    ) AS y


    UNION ALL

    SELECT RowID,
        -- add an hour to the currentHour each time the recursive CTE is called
        DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) AS currentHour,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour)) AS hourOrdinal,
        CAST(CASE
            -- when this is the last time period determine the amount of the hour that is applicable
            WHEN DATEADD(hour, 2, currentHour) > ShiftEnd THEN DATEPART(minute, ShiftEnd) / 60.0
            ELSE 1
        END AS DECIMAL(5,3)) AS hourValue
    FROM shiftHours
    -- contine recursion until the next hour is after the ShiftEnd
    WHERE DATEADD(hour, 1, currentHour) < ShiftEnd
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RowID,
        ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd,
        hourValue,
        hourOrdinal
    FROM shiftHours
) AS t
PIVOT (
    SUM(hourValue)
    FOR hourOrdinal IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
) AS pvt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Hey,Thank you for your help :) 

So it means I have to use insert in the query? is there any other alternatives without using insert/delete/update etc? as I do not want to change anyth in the database

Comment: @dataTable is a table variable. It doesn't create a table anywhere

Comment: The table creation and insert statements just create some data to work with to show how the queries work. They aren't necessary since you already have tables with that data in them. You will need to adapt the actual SQL query below that to work with your tables instead of the example ones I'm using.

Comment: Hi it works, however theres this error message.  

    Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
    Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
@MikeD.

Comment: That will be due to the fact that your ShiftStart and ShiftEnd columns are strings instead of proper DATETIME data type. Do you have any control over the source system schema? The ideal solution is to convert these to the right data type. Not as good would be to add a view to the database that will handle the conversion that way you don't need to do it in every query.

Comment: If you can't modify the database you'll need to do the conversion in your query. Of course doing a conversion leaves you at the mercy of bad data. At any point they could change the format of the date string or some row will come in with a value that isn't even a date. Then all your code is broken until they fix the data or you have to code very defensively and try to toss out any data that doesn't work.

Comment: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

This error pop up now. isit related to the ID?
@MikeD.

Comment: No that is due to the default limit for recursion that MSSQL has. You can get around it by using `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` which removes the limit. (See the updated example query #2.)

Comment: Yeah I tried adding  `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` and the error message shows `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.`
@MikeD.

Comment: Make sure you remove the semicolon after `pvt`, otherwise I'm a bit stumped on that one...

Comment: Hii, the query have been executed for 2 hours with no results ):
@MikeD.

Comment: Is it a very large table?

Comment: After some testing I get results for 1000 rows back in about 1 second, 10,000 rows takes about 13 seconds and 100,000 rows takes about 9 minutes and 46 seconds. It isn't a beefy server and there are no indexes on the table. I'm also not doing any data type conversions since my table has DATETIME values in it which would make your version a bit slower. But clearly the query doesn't scale to processing hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: If you're running this on more than a few thousand rows at a time you may want to look at a different solution such as storing the pre-calculated values for each shift so your reports run quickly. That would also allow you to do any data conversions before running queries against it which would be helpful.

Comment: Hi I did a  `SELECT TOP 1000 `and it managed to run. However the results are not there yet.
I have screenshot the output and placed it in the last part of my question above. Please take a look, thanks a lot! appreciated 
@MikeD.

Comment: Looks like however you are converting your strings to dates isn't working. Odd that it is showing all of those hours as worked though... that is unexpected. Though I can't say I tested `WHERE StartTime=EndTime`

Comment: Even passing in those values manually I don't see the same results you do. However, this is a bug if the shift is less than one hour long as the code is still treating that as a full hour (`1.0` in the results).

Comment: Hmm any suggestions on what I can do now? btw have updated the query on the qns above 
@MikeD.

Comment: Yeah I've seen you added the query that you're using which is helpful. You're converting the times in far too many places. You only need to do it once, in the top query of the recursive CTE. After that everything should be a DATETIME anyway. That might fix up your issue of having all of the shifts come through as 1900. I'll have to look into it more later tonight...

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the actual query that you will probably need to use. I have made some assumptions so you might need to modify it a bit but it should get you what you need. I've also put some comments in there as to where you would add filtering from the source table which could allow it to be used in a report with a date range filter so that it doesn't take two hours to run.

Comment: ok, will check it out! @MikeD.
anyw do u have any idea how to solve one of my other question on: Calculating columns vertically?? Using the same concept, but the purpose is on headcount this time round

Comment: Hi @MikeD. This code is able to execute successfully in SQL. However, tableau do not support SQL Server CTE feature.  
 is there any way to convert this CTE query into subquery?

Comment: easiest way would be to create a view that uses this query as it's definition. otherwise, since it is a recursive CTE you can't just copy it inline into the query and have it work as a normal table expression.

Comment: @MikeD.
hmm how do we create view? Have to modify the whole query?

Comment: it seems like im unable to add the view due to the MAXRECURSION. theres this error output "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'."
May I know how to solve this issue? @MikeD.

Comment: This will explain it: http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2010/04/12/maxrecursion-with-a-cte-in-a-view/

Comment: Instead of calculating from SHIFTA_START to SHIFTA_END, can we calculate from SHIFTA_START to 2359 on the same date itself? 
eg1: SHIFTA_START: 2015-03-01 08:30:00.000,
        SHIFTA_END : 2015-03-01 19:30:00.000
-- This duration does not involve overnight.

eg2: SHIFTA_START: 2015-03-01 17:30:00.000,
        SHIFTA_END : 2015-03-02 07:00.000
-- For overnight duration, I want to populate from 2015-03-01 17:30:00.000 to 2015-03-01 23:59:00.000.

Is that possible? @MikeD.

Answer (score 1):

this should gives you what you wanted.

```
; 
with cte as
(
    select  *, 
        hr_st1 = case   when datepart(hour, SHIFTA_Start) < datepart(hour, SHIFTA_End)
                then datepart(hour, SHIFTA_Start)
                else 0
                end, 
        hr_en1 = datepart(hour, SHIFTA_End),
        hr_st2 = case   when datepart(hour, SHIFTA_Start) > datepart(hour, SHIFTA_End)
                then datepart(hour, SHIFTA_Start)
                end,
        hr_en2 = case   when datepart(hour, SHIFTA_Start) > datepart(hour, SHIFTA_End)
                then 23
                end
    from    @shift s
)
select  *,
    CASE    WHEN    0 BETWEEN hr_st1 and hr_en1 
        OR  0 BETWEEN hr_st2 and hr_en2 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END AS [0],
    CASE    WHEN    1 BETWEEN hr_st1 and hr_en1 
        OR  1 BETWEEN hr_st2 and hr_en2 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END AS [1],
    CASE    WHEN    2 BETWEEN hr_st1 and hr_en1 
        OR  2 BETWEEN hr_st2 and hr_en2 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END AS [2],
    CASE    WHEN    3 BETWEEN hr_st1 and hr_en1 
        OR  3 BETWEEN hr_st2 and hr_en2 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END AS [3]
from    cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way harder than it needs to be. Use the DateTime as is and use a calculated column to give you minutes worked (or hours).

```
    create table WorkTimes
    (
    Id int not null identity,
    SHIFTA_Start DateTime not null,
    SHIFTA_End DateTime,
    MinutesWorked AS CASE WHEN SHIFTA_End IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SHIFTA_Start, SHIFTA_End)
        END,
    constraint WorkTimes_Check_Shift 
               check (SHIFTA_End IS NULL OR SHIFTA_Start < SHIFTA_End),
    constraint WorkTimes_Check_Shift_Too_Long 
               check (SHIFTA_End IS NULL OR datediff(hour, SHIFTA_Start, SHIFTA_End) < 22)
    )
```

So the MinutesWorked will always be correct. No need to have code to account for daylight savings time, year change, working overnight, etc.

Now that you have the correct data type you can calculate what you want.

```
declare @start datetime = '4/27/2016 22:10', @stop datetime = '4/28/2016 05:20'  

select h.[Hour],
round(cast(case when @start > h.hour then 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, @start) 
when @stop < h.hour then DATEPART(minute, @stop)
else 60 end as decimal(5, 2)) / 60, 2) PercentHour
from [dbo].HoursBetween(@start, @stop) h
order by h.[Hour]
```

This creates:

[image]

The function I used is:

```
create function [dbo].[HoursBetween](@Start datetime, @Stop datetime)
returns @Hours TABLE
(
[Hour] DateTime
)
begin

declare @temp datetime 

set @Start = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @Start, 120) + ':00' as datetime)

set @temp = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @Stop, 120) + ':00' as datetime)

if(@temp <> @Stop)
    set @Stop = DATEADD(hour, 1, @temp)

while(@Start <= @Stop)
begin
    insert into @Hours 
    values(@Start)

    set @Start = DATEADD(hour, 1, @Start)
end

return;
end

GO
```

Comment: Correct data types would go a long way towards making this easier (and computed columns are certainly handy) but this table structure doesn't actually give the information requested in the question. They want a column for each hour of the day to be populated with the percentage of that hour that was worked in the shift. This just gives the total minutes worked for the entire shift.